# Best data structure to hold elements whose elements can be later distributed among stakeholders?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to develop an UNO card game, and now I reach to a point where I need a data structure that can hold the whole deck, and then I can take pieces of it and distribute it among several places (The players, the discard pile, and the draw pile). The code would be something like this:

```
public class UnoGame
{
    public UnoGame()
    {
        SomeDataStructure<Card> unoDeck = generateUnoCards();
        List<Cards> player1 = unoDeck.get(7);
        List<Cards> player2 = unoDeck.get(7);
        List<Cards> discardPile = unoDeck.get(1);
        List<Cards> drawPile = unoDeck.getRest();
    }

    private static SomeDataStructure<Card> generateUnoCards()
    {
        SomeDataStructure<Card> cards = new SomeDataStructure<Card>(108);
        // Here we can create the proper cards and add them to the data structre
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        return cards;
    }
}
```

So, it there any built-in data structure in Java that fits my requirements? Or should I implement my own data structure?

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>>? Even better: HashMap<String, ArrayList<Card>>. Key is name, arraylist is cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear why you need anything special. I would model it as per the real game: a stack for all the cards (using `LinkedList<T>` as the stack implementation), which you then take cards off to get a hand, and which is *also* used to fetch cards later. I would model each *player* with a separate class though... even if initially it just contains a `List<Card>` or something similar.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
LinkedList<Card> deck = createDeck(); // This should shuffle too
for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
    Player player = new Player();
    players.add(player);
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        player.addCard(deck.removeLast());
    }
}
LinkedList<Card> discards = new LinkedList<Card>();
```

At every point, if you think about what would happen in the physical game, it should be reasonably easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either an ArrayList of an ArrayList or a HashMap

ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> decks = generateUnoCards();
ArrayList<Card> player1 = decks.get(0);
...
```

HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Card>> decks = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Card>>();
decks.put("player1", new ArrayList<Card>);
...
decks.put("drawPile", getRest(decks));
...
ArrayList<Card> drawPile = decks.get("drawPile");
```

When a session ends and you want to shuffle the deck, copy everything out of the non-drawPile Arraylists into drawPile, call clear() on those ArrayLists, and then call Collections.sort() on your drawPile. Then re-deal the cards.

Comment: But, in this way, the cards inside the player 1 list will be same on every session in the game

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to remove a card, use `decks.get("player1").remove(card);`. If you want to add a card, use `decks.get("player1").add(card);` See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I mean, after creating the 108 uno cards, I have to store them into a data structure so that I can use `Collections.shuffle(cards);` to ensure they will be in a different order on every uno game session. The solution you suggested, I cannot shuffle the elements because they will be in different data strucures. I mean, on calling `decks.put("player1", new ArrayList<Card>);`, what cards should I add to the arraylist?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Then you can empty the other decks, put all cards in the drawPile, shuffle the drawPile, then redistribute.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Perhaps each new game, you should create a brand new `drawPile`, a brand new `decks`, and distribute the cards from `drawPile` into `decks`.